# Facebook messenger webhook won't receive any messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I created a webhook for facebook, the subscription worked fine, (See the JSon result below). But whenever i send a message to the page, the webhook doesn't receive anything, the only entries from the webhook that i receive is when i subscribed to the page.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "object": "page",
         "callback_url": "https://{MY_DOMAIN}.nl/facebookmessenger/webhook/index.php",
         "fields": [
            "conversations",
            "message_deliveries",
            "messages",
            "messaging_account_linking",
            "messaging_optins",
            "messaging_postbacks"
         ],
         "active": true
      }
   ]
}
```

I know for a reason that the webhook page itself works. So i don't feel the need to add it here.

If there's anything else you need to ask, you're free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, i feel dumb. I linked everything up, but forgot to put the page i'm using on the developers.facebook.com at the messenger webhook. Sorry about that haha

Comment: Sorry. Could you help me? I have a same problem with you.